# haskell cannot construct the infinite type

Tags: loops, haskell, where-clause

I thought the following code should work:

```
sum_up x = loop_it 0 x
    where loop_it sum i | i > 0     = loop_it sum+i i-1
                        | i == 0    = sum
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
<interactive>:3:15: error:
    • Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type:
        t2 ~ (t0 -> t2) -> t2
      Expected type: t2 -> t2
        Actual type: t2 -> (t0 -> t2) -> t2
    • In an equation for ‘sum_up’:
          sum_up x
            = loop_it 0 x
            where
                loop_it sum i
                  | i > 0 = loop_it sum + i i - 1
                  | i == 0 = sum
    • Relevant bindings include
        loop_it :: t2 -> t2 (bound at <interactive>:3:15)
```

Why doesn't this compile?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need parentheses around the arguments of the recursive call to `loop_it`:

```
sum_up x = loop_it 0 x
    where loop_it sum i | i > 0     = loop_it (sum+i) (i-1)  -- <- Here
                        | i == 0    = sum
```

If you don't group it like that, the compiler would implicitly group it like this:

```
((loop_it sum)+(i i))-1
```

... which is probably not what you wanted, since that means: "apply `loop_it` to `sum`, then add that to `i i` (i.e. `i` applied to itself), then subtract 1.

This happens because function application has highest precedence in Haskell, so function application binds more tightly than arithmetic.